Type Mismatch based on Tutorial
Following a tutorial to delete empty cells in a table I keep getting a type mismatch error and I can't understand why. From what I can see DataBodyRange returns a range but the issue seems to present itself for the For Each row In rng.Rows line.
Is this jumping out to anyone?
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As ListRow
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawIPs")
    
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        Set rng = tbl.DataBodyRange
        
        For Each row In rng.Rows
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(row) = 0 Then
                row.Delete
            End If
        Next row
    Next tbl


Try to dimension row as row and not as ListRow

@Shrotter, that generates the following error:  User-defined type not defined

He meant As Range.

Delete Blank Rows

I guess you're a victim of bad AI code. This looks exactly like what ChatGPT would answer minus the comments. AI-generated code is banned from SO i.e. it can be used in questions but not answers.
I found almost the same code here where the answerer even confirms it: "The text, the code and steps were edited with the help of AI.".

The Issues

A range doesn't have a ListRow property.
When deleting single rows, you must loop backward to delete each row successfully. Otherwise, when there are two consecutive blank (empty) rows, the second one will not be deleted.
If one of the tables is empty, an error will occur.

A Working Code

Note that COUNTBLANK, besides empty cells, also includes cells with formulas evaluating to an empty string or such cells copied as values. If you want only to consider empty cells, use COUNTA as it is used in the AI code.

Compact
Sub DeleteBlankRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawIPs")
    
    Dim lo As ListObject, rg As Range, urg As Range, rrg As Range
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        If lo.ListRows.Count > 0 Then ' table is not empty
            Set rg = lo.DataBodyRange
            ColumnsCount = rg.Columns.Count
            IsFirstFound = False ' reset for each table
            For Each rrg In rg.Rows
                If Application.CountBlank(rrg) = ColumnsCount Then ' is blank
                    If IsFirstFound Then ' all after first
                        Set urg = Union(urg, rrg)
                    Else ' first
                        Set urg = rrg
                        IsFirstFound = True
                    End If
                'Else ' is not blank
                End If
            Next rrg
            If IsFirstFound Then ' row ranges found
                urg.Delete xlShiftUp
            'Else ' no row ranges found
            End If
        'Else ' table is empty
        End If
    Next lo
    
    MsgBox "Blank rows deleted from all tables.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

Refactored
Main
Sub DeleteBlankRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawIPs")
    
    Dim lo As ListObject
    
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        If lo.ListRows.Count > 0 Then ' table is not empty
            DeleteBlankRowsInRange lo.DataBodyRange
        'Else ' table is empty
        End If
    Next lo
    
    MsgBox "Blank rows deleted from all tables.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

Help
Sub DeleteBlankRowsInRange(ByVal rg As Range)
    
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim urg As Range, rrg As Range, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For Each rrg In rg.Rows
        If Application.CountBlank(rrg) = ColumnsCount Then ' is blank
            If IsFirstFound Then ' all after first
                Set urg = Union(urg, rrg)
            Else ' first
                Set urg = rrg
                IsFirstFound = True
            End If
        'Else ' is not blank
        End If
    Next rrg
    
    If IsFirstFound Then ' row ranges found
        urg.Delete xlShiftUp
    'Else ' no row ranges found
    End If

End Sub


That is exactly where I found that code snippet but I missed the line at the end referencing AI. Regardless, are you able to shed light on why deleting empty rows in a range is a few lines of code while deleting empty rows in a table requires so much more effort?

Practically the same code is used to delete blank rows in a range. It requires more lines of code to make it more efficient. I'll shortly post a shorter code that calls a helper method which you can use for ranges.
